# Azure pipelines unable to locate MIDL compiler

Tags: azure-devops, midl

I'm trying to move a Visual Studio project into Azure pipelines.  This project uses the MIDL compiler, but when running in the pipeline midl.exe is not found:

```
(Midl target) -> 
  TRACKER : error TRK0005: Failed to locate: "midl.exe". The system cannot find the file specified.
```

I cannot find any reference to MIDL in the Azure pipelines documentation, or anything about the Windows SDK more generally, as I assume it would be preinstalled when using one of the Windows VM images

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'windows-2019'
```

currently using 'windows-2019' as we need to make some updates to the project's dependencies before I can update it to 'windows-latest'

Is this an issue of just not having it in the `PATH` when running the pipeline or is it actually not installed in the default VM image?  If so how would I view the VM workspace to know what path value to add/how would I go about installing it?

Comment: I believe MIDL should be in the vmImage. What kind of task are you using to run the build of your project? Are you using an `MSBuild` task or a `Visual Studio build` task or something else? Can you show the relevant YAML?

Comment: Here is the [Installed Windows SDKs](https://github.com/actions/runner-images/blob/main/images/win/Windows2019-Readme.md#installed-windows-sdks) on vmImage windows-2019.   It is preinstalled.

Comment: It's running the `VSBuild@1` task, and I confirmed that the SDK was present by adding a script to show the contents of the Program Files(x86) directory.  I eventually made it work by adding this script before the VSBuild task to locate and run `vsdevcmd.bat` which sets the necessary values in the path: https://gist.github.com/devhawk/2d8cb579f179ed659e3862c860d846d6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this issue by running the `vsdevcmd.bat` script in the pipeline to get all the necessary variables set in the environment.  I found [this link on github](https://gist.github.com/devhawk/2d8cb579f179ed659e3862c860d846d6) to a pipeline script that locates the appropriate version using the `vswhere` command